# Weird Behaviour in jQuery's html method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any good reason why $("p").html(0) makes all paragraphs empty as opposed to contain the character '0'?

Instead of assuming I found a bug in jQuery, it's probably a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Your wording is confusing. Maybe: "...as opposed to containing the character 0?" btw, $('p').html('0') works.

Comment: Yeah, I know it works, just not what I need.  Found a work around anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery only accepts a string as an argument for the `val` parameter of the `html()` method.  If you pass a number like you are it will call the `html()` method override that sets the contents of the element but the value of the argument will end up being null or an empty string.

Try this:

```
$("p").html((0).toString())
```

[Relevant documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val)

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: that should be (0).toString(). Otherwise it parses the period as part of the number and gets a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that at some point, it checks `if (newContent == false)`, and doesn't continue with adding any content? I tried looking at the source, but got a bit lost...

I also guess that this would not be counted as a bug, since the function calls for a string, and if "0" is passed (as a string), it works as expected.

A workaround would be to do this:

```
var myNum = 0;
$('p').html('' + myNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `text()` instead `html()`.

Answer (score 0):

The code performing the html call was within someone else's plugin and rather than modify it, making upgrading it tedious, I just wrote the following tiny plugin that modifies the `html` method to do as spoon16 recommended.

```
(function($) {
  var oldHtml = $.fn.html;
  $.fn.html = function (content) {
    oldHtml.apply(this, [content.toString()]);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

It's a little bit of a hack, but it's working for me and doesn't require me to modify the Plugin I'm using.

I just thought someone else might like to see this.

Answer (score -1):

I geuss you missed part of how jQuery works,

```
$('p')
```

returns all paragraphs and the html( val ) function:

```
Set the html contents of every matched element. This property is not available on XML documents (although it will work for XHTML documents).
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val
So if you just want to set the contents for the first p use

```
$("P").eq(0).html( 'something' );
```

or to get the html:

```
$("P").eq(0).html();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq#position
more on jQuery selectors here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: I understand how it works, I just noted the behavior when it's passed the number 0.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I though you meant why it didn't contain the html for the 1st paragraph